# How to pass the value of variable one controller to another controller's gsp

Tags: grails

Grails Question:

Q :- How i pass the one int value from one controller to another controller's .gsp page ?

like 
I have Customer Controller i want to pass customer id value to address Controller's .gsp file to store address for particular customer ..

can any one help me Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want as

from  Customer Controller's action

```
 redirect(controller: "address", action: "show", id: 4, params: [intValue: "intValue"])
```

and you cand get  `intValue` at your Address controller's `show` action  as

```
params.intValue as Integer
```

Comment: I want to pass customer id value which i have as sequence in databse and using this id i want to save the address .